# Bitmap as status bar icon

Tags: android

Using notificationCompat, you can only set the small icon for notifications through its ID, so I've been looking for a workaround to display live temperature as a status bar Icon.

What I'm currently working with:

LayerDrawable has the ability to replace a drawable in the layer, so I've converted the temperature String to a bitmap drawable and replaced the layer.  The replacement seems to be working but the original drawable still shows.  Any ideas?

Layer Drawable (I've tried with a blank png and an all white png):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/temp_foreground">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/blank_white"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Setting the small icon:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    mBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.status_bar_temp);
    Drawable temp = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), convertTempToBitmap(StringUtils.appendDegree(getTemperature())));
    boolean success = ld.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.temp_foreground, temp);
    if (success) {
        ld.invalidateSelf();
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.status_bar_temp);
    }
```

Here's the generated bitmap (if that helps):
[image]

Comment: That's not going to work. Notice that you're passing the resource ID in `setSmallIcon()`, not the `Drawable` instance that you create and modify there. The process that handles the `Notification` is going to retrieve the `status_bar_temp` resource as that XML, and create its own instance there (grabbing your `blank_white` resource as well). Any changes you make to a dynamically created instance are not reflected in the static resource in your package.

Comment: Ugh. Can you think of any other way?

Comment: Well, starting with API 23, I'm pretty sure you can set an [`Icon`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html) as the small icon, and there's a lot of flexibility with that class, as far as creating the backing image. Prior to 23, I believe the usual way of handling that would be to just have a bunch of pre-made images in your drawable resources, and picking the appropriate one to show, as needed, whether they're all separate images, or packed into a [`LevelListDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html)

Comment: The issue is that on random samsung phones, I get a RemoteServiceException: Couldn't update icon when using setSmallIcon(icon)